# How to check the return type of response.json() after a fetch() in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, promise, fetch-api

I am using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in TypeScript, but I don't know how to correctly check the response type of the data after the *response.json()*.

The problem I'm having is that even if the type generated after *response.json()* is of a type other than `TResponse`, the object is still returned. I'd like an exception to be thrown in this case... Even if the response status is OK

Here is the code :

```js
/*
 * The types
 */

interface ICredentials {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

interface ISession {
  token: string;
}
```

```js
/*
 * The post function
 */
const api = {
  post: async <TBody, TResponse>(url: string, bodyParams?: TBody) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/${url}`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyParams),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = (await response.json()) as Promise<TResponse>;
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  },
};
```

```js
/*
 * My login function
 */
async login(data: ICredentials) {
    try {
      return await api.post<ICredentials, ISession>("users", data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("loginError", e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime. The metadata is erased in transpilation to JavaScript. The interfaces will be removed entirely and you'll have nothing to check against. The type assertion is just to help the compiler help you, it is also removed and will not (_can_ not) cause any runtime errors.